# Passing values from activity to fragment getting NullPointerException error

Tags: android, android-activity, arguments, fragment, bundle

I try to pass values to my fragment from my Activity but I getting NullPointerException error.
this is the code

Activity.java

```
String name = "checkout";
Fragment myFragment= new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment.java

```
assert getArguments() != null;
String name = getArguments().getString("name");
```

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: we need entire code fragment to help you identify what causes bug just this info isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to create fragment.

On activity :

```
String name = "checkout";
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);

MyFragment.newInstance(bundle)
```

On Fragment :

```
fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle?): MyFragment? {
        if (bundle == null)
            return null

        val fragment = MyFragment()
        fragment.mUserId = bundle.getString("name")
        return fragment
    }
```

Tell me if it's good

Comment: please tell me is this java?